# Where can I find open source code for Encryption Switching Protocol?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation

The concept of [Encryption Switching Protocols](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/data/paper.php?pubkey=27712) was introduced in CRYPTO.

I was wondering if there is any pseudo-implementation of the protocol available or can I get some insights on how to implement it?

Comment: contact the author, they might give you

Answer (score 4):

I am one of the authors of this paper. We did not implement encryption switching protocols, and as far as I know, they were never implemented. If you plan to implement them, I will be happy to answer questions about specific points. However, I cannot really give general insights about how to implement them: it's a long paper, with a relatively large number of rather complex constructions. The first step would probably be to implement our new variant of ElGamal - good implementations of the Paillier encryption scheme, which we also use, are already available.